# Django form action attribute is not working propely

Tags: python, django, forms, elasticsearch, search

I am working on app in django 1.11, on search feature. I installed elasticsearch - here all things are working.

In base.html and under url `127.0.0.1:8000` - I have form to search and I would like to keep this form here. On another hand I have search app with view, url, template - under url `127.0.0.1:8000/search/` - search is working here.

To solve this problem - search on main page and redirect on site with results I was trying to use `action` attribute in django form.

form in base.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'search:search' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" {% if request.GET.q %}value="{{ request.GET.q }}"{% endif %} name="q" placeholder="Search">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">GO</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

view in search app

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
        posts = PostDocument.search().query('match', title=q)
    else:
        posts = ''
    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'posts': posts})
```

template with results

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for p in posts %}
        <a href="#">{{ p.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
{% block sidebar %}{% endblock sidebar %}
```

Comment: Your `method="post"`, but you obtain a `request.GET` parameter. Either you make the `method="get"`, or you change to `request.POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You here mix up GET and POST. If the method is `method="post"`, then the data is passed in the request, and thus ends up in the `request.POST` query dictionary.

If on the other hand the method is `method="get"`, then the data ends up in the *querystring* of the URL. In that case, you can indeed use `request.GET`.

Often (not always), search queries are done with querystrings, since then a person can copy the URL and send it to another person, and that person thus can see the search results.

You can thus change the form to:

```
<form action="{% url 'search:search' %}" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" {% if request.GET.q %}value="{{ request.GET.q }}"{% endif %} name="q" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">GO</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot it is working. Can you give me a hint, how to implement querystrings, to better link, to share?

Comment: @user10605113: here we *are* using querystrings. If you want to use a post request, in your view you should replace `request.GET.get(..)` with `request.POST.get(..)`.